# Check if entry has a descendant with a certain field enabled

Tags: templating, entries, structure

Whew, complicated thing to described in a short subject line! :)

Okay, so I have a structure like this:

---

- Asia

  - Peking

    - weekend ( field `howLongWillYouBeGoing` == 'shortStay' )
    - long weekend ( field `howLongWillYouBeGoing` == 'mediumStay' )
    - week ( field `howLongWillYouBeGoing` == 'longStay' )
- Europe

  - Peking

    - weekend ( field `howLongWillYouBeGoing` == 'shortStay' )
- South America
  (no subpages)

---

I have a navigation bar that just lists the continents and turns them into a link as soon as it has descendants. When it doesn't have descendants, it just shows the continent name as a non-clickable text.

Now this is the thing. I have used the following code, but it doesn't work. It still shows Europe in this example as a link, even though I believe the conditions are not met. I would LOVE love love any input because I've been staring myself blind on this the last few hours :)

```
{# loop through continents #}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('destinations').type('continent').find() %}
    {# only show links to continent pages if it has any travelguides #}
    {% if entry.hasDescendants(3) %}

        {% set mediumStay = 0 %}
        {% for subPage in entry.getDescendants(2) %}
            {% if subPage.howLongWillYouBeGoing == 'mediumStay' %}
                {% set mediumStay = 1 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if mediumStay == 1 %}
            {# if subpage is marked as mediumstay, show a link to it #}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == entry.slug %}class="is-active"{% endif %}>{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @lindsey-d thank you for cleaning up my code! I was struggling a bit there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow - thanks for listening ;-)

I solved it like this:

```
{# loop through continents #}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('destinations').type('continent').find() %}   
    {# only show links to continent pages if it has any travelguides #}
    {% if entry.hasDescendants() %}
        {% set continentID = entry.id %}
        {% if entry.howLongWillYouBeGoing == 'mediumStay' in craft.entries.section('destinations').descendantOf(continentID) %}
            {# if subpage is marked as mediumstay, show a link to it #}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == entry.slug %}class="is-active"{% endif %}>{{ entry.title }}</a></li>  
        {% else %} 
            {# if it's not a mediumStay, just show the text #}
            <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
        {% endif %} 
    {% else %} 
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```